# What is * in AT command?

Tags: protocols, robotics, at-command

I came accros this kind of line in a proprietary use of the AT commands:

> AT*REF=1,290717696<LF>

It is a proprietary command as it is used in a protocol to control a robot.

According to what I read on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set#Description) and other sources, AT command extensions should use "\" or "%". There is no mention of "*".

So what does `*` define?

Comment: Every thing after 'AT' processed bu the modem ( or any other serial device). You should check the manual of the robot.

Comment: My question is not about the command, but about the choice of * in the command.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than two different characters in use by various manufacturers when implementing the first character of a proprietary AT command.  Some that I've seen:

! @ # $ % ^ * _

The manufacturer of your device may have chosen '*' for commands that have similar functionality, or they may have chosen to implement ALL of their proprietary AT commands with '*' as the first character.

There are many AT command references available online in PDF format from many different manufacturers.  Perhaps the manufacturer of your device makes this information available as well.